# How to get the visible list items count in a Xamarin android Array adapter

Tags: listview, xamarin, adapter

I'm currently working on Xamarin android mobile application. There I have a requirement for displaying 50 list items using ArrrayAdapter in a 10-inch mobile screen.

When a mobile screen displays page with list items, It's showing by default 10 items at first. If I scroll further down it is showing items from 5 to 15. And if I scroll further it is showing 11 to 20.

At any given point of time, it is capable of displaying only 10 items.

How can I get the count(In ArrayAdapter GetView method) based on the screen size of the phone (in my case 10)?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Veswanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android the ListView has two properties that should help:

```
int start = listView.FirstVisiblePosition;
int end = listView.LastVisiblePosition;
```

So Subtract start from end and add 1 to get the total visible items, e.g.:

```
int numberOfVisibleItems = end - start + 1;
```

Note I did not test this, but it should work as long as you do this after the list is fully populated and displayed.  Note that if even a sliver of a list item is in view, it will be counted.

EDIT: How to get the listView reference in GetView()

The `ViewGroup parent` parameter of `GetView(...)` should be the `ListView`, so in GetView(...):

```
 ListView listView = parent as ListView;
 int start = listView.FirstVisiblePosition;
 int end = listView.LastVisiblePosition;
 int numberOfVisibleItems = end - start + 1;
```

Comment: Thaks jgoldberger. But I want to get the count in GetView() in ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please accept it if it works for you (it should)